# Given a list of strings, how can I check if those strings are in a list in Scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have list of keywords

```
val mykeywords = Array("Glass", "Bone China", "Ceramic", "Clock")
```

I have dataframe

```
val df = Seq("Title1", "Title2", "glass", "CloCK").toDF("Title)
```

I want to generate dataframe

**Title Flag**
Title1   0
Title2   0
glass    1
CloCK    1

My Current Code

```
val mykeywords: Array[String] = Array("Glass", "Bone China", "Ceramic", "Clock").map(_.toLowerCase())
val df2 = df.withColumn("Flag", lower(col("Title")).rlike(mykeywords.mkString("|")).cast(IntegerType))
```

Which is currently not working properly for some string matches, Please point out if there is better way

Comment: Can you provide what is the error or the scenario that you code is not working ??

Comment: It says true for match of "wailed" with "led"

Answer (score 1):

Convert `mykeywords` into a dataframe too and `right` `join` both data frames on values in case insensitive way. Replace `null` match with `0` and non-null match with `1`.

```
df
.join(right = mykeywordsDf, joinType = "right", joinExprs = lower(df("Title")).equalTo(lower(mykeywordsDf("Title")))
.withColumn(
   "Flag", 
   when(mykeywordsDf("Title").isNull, 0)
    .when(mykeywordsDf("Title").isNotNull, 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is nearly correct just you have to put string literal in `rlike` like this

```
df.withColumn("Flag", col("Title").rlike("(?i)^"+ mykeywords.mkString("|")+ "$").cast("Integer")).show()
```

This above code will work.

Comment: If it solves your given problem then accept the answer so that other peeps might get help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [inin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#isin(scala.collection.Seq)) function to check if column expression is contained in your `mykeywords` list:

```
df.withColumn("Flag", 
              lower(col("Title")).isin(mykeywords.map(_.toLowerCase): _*).cast("int")
             ).show()
```

Output:

```
+------+----+
| Title|Flag|
+------+----+
|Title1|   0|
|Title2|   0|
| glass|   1|
| CloCK|   1|
+------+----+
```